# What are the changes to a character caused by Wereraven Lycanthropy from the Curse of Strahd adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, curse-of-strahd, lycanthropy

I just had a player contract wereraven lycanthropy in my *Curse of Strahd* campaign, but I can't find the changes that they would get for having it.

Where are the effects of wereraven lycanthropy described?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 12):

The specifics for [wereraven](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cos/appendix-d-monsters-and-npcs#Wereraven) lycanthropy can be found on page 242 of the *Curse of Strahd* adventure book.

The more general rules for player characters as [lycanthropes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-l#Lycanthropes) can be found on page 207 of the *Monster Manual*.